# MySql Pivot table in to Yii CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I have a table structure as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CustomValue` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customFieldId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relatedId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldValue` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CustomField` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customTypeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `relatedTable` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `defaultValue` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `sortOrder` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enabled` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
  `listItemTag` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `required` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `onCreate` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
  `onEdit` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
  `onView` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
  `listValues` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `label` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `htmlOptions` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address1` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `mobile` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4034 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Please check the SQL fiddle as well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a579/3

The data is loaded with this query.

```
SET @Colvalues = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(f.fieldName = ''',
      f.fieldName, ''', COALESCE(v.fieldValue, f.defaultValue) , NULL)) AS ', '''', f.fieldName , '''')
  ) INTO @Colvalues
FROM customField AS f
INNER JOIN Customvalue AS v ON f.Id = v.customFieldId;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
    u.*, v.relatedId, v.CreatedAt, ', @Colvalues , '
FROM customField AS f
INNER JOIN Customvalue AS v ON f.Id = v.customFieldId RIGHT JOIN User u on u.id = v.relatedId
GROUP BY   v.relatedId, v.CreatedAt;');

PREPARE stmt 
FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

How can I form this to a `CDbCriteria` object and `CActiveDataProvider` ? I need to load these data in to a `cgridview` and allow custom columns to be searched with `cgridview filters`.

currently this is what I have done:

```
public function searchPeople($customFields)
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->together = true;

        $criteria->compare('address1', $this->address1, true);
        $criteria->compare('mobile', $this->mobile, true);
        $criteria->compare('t.firstName', $this->firstName, true);
        $criteria->compare('t.lastName', $this->lastName, true);


        if (!empty($customFields)) {
            $criteria->join .= ' LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomValue cv ON cv.relatedId=t.id';
            //foreach ($customFields as $k => $customField) {
            //print_r($customField); exit;
            //}
        }
```

**output of print_r($customField):**

```
CustomValue Object
(
    [fieldStyle] => 
    [fieldName] => ALTERNATEEMAIL
    [fieldLabel] => Alternate Email
    [fieldType] => text
    [fieldTag] => 
    [fieldIsRequired] => 1
    [fieldDefaultValue] => 
    [listValues] => 
    [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 1
    [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [customFieldId] => 14
            [fieldValue] => 
        )
```

Comment: it might help to explain what is not working with what you have so far... Or be more specific about the problem you have in implementing it

Comment: @clickstefan this is my query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a579/3 i need to filter the records based on dynamic columns.  i am trying to first setup this format to a CDbCriteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a SQL View and then a new Model from this?

The SQL does not contain dynamic value, it should be written in more compact form.

Comment: creating a VIEW for Dynamic queries is not possible in MYSQL.